# Use full height in mobile browse with retracting address bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-browser

I have a web page where I want to use the full height (no more, no less) of the screen with two stacked divs, so that the second div fills out the height that remains after the first one.

At the moment I am doing it like this:

**css**

```
body { height: 100%; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('div2').style.height =
        (document.getElementById('body').offsetHeight -
            document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight) + 'px';
}
```

This works fine, but in mobile browsers (tested on Android default browser and Chrome) the address bar remains visible, although it can be hidden and the space used for the second div. I assume similar behaviour can be expected from iPhones.

So my question is: Does anyone know how to get the available height in a mobile browser, including retractable address bar?

*edit*

Ifound this:http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/, but I can't get it to work in Chrome.

*update*

I am now using this code, but it still doesn't work in Android Chrome (and I haven't tried it in iPhones).

**JavaScript function:**

```
if(typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') {
    document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight) + 'px';
    setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 50); }, 50);
}
document.getElementById('div2').style.height =
    (document.body.offsetHeight - 
        document.getElementById('div2').offsetHeight) + 'px';
```

I am calling this function in `window.onload` and `window.onresize`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="div1">1st</div>
   <div class="div2">2nd</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
div.box { background: #EEE; height: 100%; width: 600px; }
div.div1{background: #999; height: 20%;}
div.div2{ background: #666; height: 100%; }
div.clear { clear: both; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; font-size:0pt; margin-top: -1px; }
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/wNE3R/).

Hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry, but for me it does exactly what you'd expect it to do: the box' size is expanded to 120% (div1+div2), so the "box" is 20% larger than the screen. (And I see the same effect in jsfiddle.)